# CannotPullContainerError: ref pull has been retried 1 time(s): failed to copy: httpReadSeeker: failed open with 403 error

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I've recently set up an ECS Fargate service in a private subnet having `CannotPullContainerError: ref pull has been retried 1 time(s): failed to copy: httpReadSeeker: failed open: unexpected status code https://xxx.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/v2/xxx/blobs/sha256:xxx: 403 Forbidden` error during startup. I've done some troubleshooting myself, checked private subnet routes, ACLs, service task execution role and security group, which all seem correct (comparing to a running env). But I'm still getting this error, I'm hoping to get some help, many thanks!

Checked VPC private subnet and ACL - routes to local within VPC, to 0.0.0.0 via NAT GW. ACL now allows all traffic for troubleshooting purpose.

ECS task exec role - allow ecr:* for troubleshooting purpose.

ECS security group - all traffic on service port (8080)

I also found something confusing, the error containing an URL:

`https://xxxx.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/v2/xxx/blobs/sha256:xxxx`, and the sha is different from the ECR image sha, not sure if this is expected.

Comment: that doesn't sound like a network error. A 403 Forbidden error means the network connection was established, and your access was denied due to permission issues. Do you happen to have a resource policy on the ECR repository that could be blocking access? The SHA being different may mean that you are trying to access an image that doesn't exist in the repository, which could certainly cause the error.